# How to encrypt data using RSA in JMeter

Tags: encryption, jmeter, rsa

To login to the application user credentials (login and password) have to be encrypted using the RSA public key. The public key could be extracted from the response to one of the requests. How can I encrypt user data using the extracted public key?

Comment: This is one of unfortunate consequences when someone invents own authentication protocol. It brings more issues with little to none advantages.  For JMeter you may try using custom java code (beanshell?) to encrypt the credentials. Example 
 https://nonfunctionaltestingtools.blogspot.com/2015/10/using-custom-jar-in-beanshell-sampler.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JDK Security API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/index.html) in order to generate a [signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/step3.html) based on the input data.

There are a [lot](https://smartcodeschool.blogspot.com/2014/10/rsa-example.html) of [tutorials](https://niels.nu/blog/2016/java-rsa.html) over the web with the example code you can re-use in [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) using [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) language